# How to style a button's font in CSS?

Tags: html, css, browser, fonts, cross-browser

**Update:** as it seems, the issue I'm describing in this question only affects OS X browsers.

I would like to change the `font` style of my input buttons in CSS more or less like this:

```
input[type="button"]
{
    font: italic bold 3em fantasy;
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work well in Chrome, Safari and Opera **on OS X** unless I also change the default `background-color`, which I don't want to do.

**See here: http://jsfiddle.net/S7y5B/**

[image]

So my question is simple: how can I change a button's font without also changing the background color, in a way that all browsers understand? I n the JsFiddle example above, I'd like to have Button 1 look like Button 2, but with the background color unchanged. How can this be done?

Comment: I find that hard to believe that changing font won't work without background-color.. is that whats happening really? I was able to change it in your fiddle

Comment: What does **doesn't work well** mean? The font changed and is readable to me. Is there something else you're attempting to do besides change the font? Am I missing something?  Are you talking about the padding or something?

Comment: Works fine here in Chrome 28 and Opera 12...

Comment: @hungerstar in my JSfiddle link, both buttons should look the same except for the color, but they don't :-(

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue. Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: Is everybody using Windows here? I'm running OS X here, could that be the problem?

Comment: also looks good here for chrome

Comment: From my understanding, OSX will change buttons despite normal styling done to them. Changing the border/background will remove the OSX styling.

Comment: I am on OSX and I see a tiny-little-standard button, and a large, yellow one with custom font.

Comment: I m using mac os X and see http://jsfiddle.net/S7y5B/9/ just change the font ..sorry I dont understand the Q maybe

Comment: @AlexGarulli I'm using Mountain Lion, it looks like in the screenshot for me.

Comment: I confirm, OS X requires at least a border styling for it to work.

Comment: thats strange: I put a css font inline and one one external, the inline d be having the priority nop? http://jsfiddle.net/S7y5B/11/  ???

Comment: @ft1 is ur Mac update : plugins and so on?

Comment: @AlexGarulli I'm on the current OS X version 10.8 and up-to-date, only using pretty standard plugins (Java/Flash).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S7y5B/11/ @ft1 which font u r see in those?

Comment: @AlexGarulli I'm seeing the fantasy font.

Comment: @ft1 ok cool me too - now what u see? is one yellow one red - both ariel font even the one that got inline css ariel nop?

Comment: @ft1 sorry forgot link http://jsfiddle.net/S7y5B/14/

Comment: @AlexGarulli yes, that's it.

Comment: @AlexGarulli I think you misunderstood my question, sorry, maybe I was not clear enough. I don't need to change the font of the button with yellow background; I'd like to change the font of the button without a background color set.

Comment: ok yep u can't ...u can cheat like this http://jsfiddle.net/S7y5B/17/ but in the end whats the purpose of it?

Comment: create a div with grey gradient and put the link on it

Comment: @AlexGarulli yes, those are both useful options although they don't work perfectly as a button.

Comment: obviously but u can't pretend to use what the browser do : button like that are made by browser and code interpretation certainly u can change just the bit u want.

Comment: the point is both solution works as buttons they do required an amount of HTML/CSS more than use the <input> tag - no different in functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out by myself. I'm styling the button using

```
-webkit-appearance: button;
```

The text inside the button is now rendering with the expected font without need to set the background color. The border still looks somewhat different, but that's another question.

**JSsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/S7y5B/18/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After fiddling with it, it seems OSX will change buttons despite normal styling done to them. Properties such as `height`(even when element is set to `display:block`), any `font` property and `padding` are not rendered. To see the actual styling, the element's `border` or `background` must be styled.

It seems that the `color` and `width` properties render normally.

Comment: no sorry still not clear ...in here http://jsfiddle.net/S7y5B/11/ is not the 1st button suppose to be ariel font cos css inline?

Comment: @AlexGarulli the buttons are both yellow in your examples.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot]

Your buttons do look the same.

**EDIT**
OS.X Chrome:
[image]